# Laravel Eloquent select first Characters before the decimal point

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a database table that has a column with data which is a mix of both characters and numbers. What I would like to achieve is select all characters and numbers before the decimal point. Below is how the data is in the column:

```
PO995.1
PO995.2
PO995.3
PO995.4
```

***Eloquent Query***

```
 $po_number= DB::table('supplierorders')
                    ->select('supplierorders.*')
                    ->orderby('po_number','asc')
                    ->get();
```

I would like to only select `PO995` and ignore `.xx` Is there a way I can achieve this within my query?

Thanks.

Comment: Add more information to your question. Such as field data type and migrations next time. [ask]

Comment: @HuyPhạm I will do so next time.. in this case the field data type is `varchar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, what you can try are using [Laravel Collection Map](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-map) and PHP string [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Replace `field_name` with the field in your table

```
$po_number= DB::table('supplierorders')
                        ->select('supplierorders.*')
                        ->orderby('po_number','asc')
                        ->get()
                        ->map(function($item)
                        {
                            return explode('.', $item->field_name)[0];
                        });
```

Comment: @HuyPham I have tried your solution but I am getting syntax error [link]([Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/prEgfqm.png))

Comment: @Inno Urgh oh, I made a typo mistake. I editted the answer anyway. You should've figured it out with provided docs.

Comment: @HuyPham sorted! Thanks a mill